# Rewrite image path and uppercase part of it

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been battling with the following code for ages and for some reason cannot redirect the following:

`/folder/htdocs/uk/images/my-image.jpg` >> `/folder/htdocs/images/UK/my-image.jpg`

I have tried

1. `RewriteRule ^.+/(\w){2,3}/images/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/folder/htdocs/images/$1/$2 [NC,L]`
2. `RewriteRule ^/folder/htdocs/([A-Za-a]{2,3})/images/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/folder/htdocs/images/$1/$2 [NC,L]`

And a number of variations but I still have not solved it. Please can someone advise how I can do this?

I have tried redirecting it to a file - just to capture the pattern matches but again to no avail.

Comment: so `uk/images` is becoming `images/UK` ? Is `UK` a dynamic value?

Comment: Yes it is but all the images will have the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this `RewriteMap` defined in your Apache server config (vhost):

```
RewriteMap uc int:toupper
```

Have this rule inside `htdocs/.htaccess` directory (create it if it doesn't exist):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/([a-z]{2})/images/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/images/${uc:%2}/%3 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry but the UK/uk could be de/DE so this needs to vary and convert to uppercase, but this is certainly in the right direction.

Comment: I have two user accounts but yes - I do have control